# Password Migration from Django to Mysql

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, sha256, pbkdf2

Hello I have my existing web application in `Django`. Now I am migrating to `node js` and I am using the `bcrypt` algorithm for hashing the password. So, the problem is: In Django , it uses `pbkdf2_sha256` algorithm for storing password. How do I migrate password from Django so that my matching algorithm match the peviously stored password correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the node.js `crypto.pbkdf2` function, see [crypto.pbkdf2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback). PBKDF2 is the suggested passsword hashing method in the NIST SP 800-63-3 Draft document.